# Xamarin Forms: How to capture the time spend on a page

Tags: xamarin.forms, time-tracking

I need to capture the time a user spends on a page in my application.

I wish the time is in **hour: minutes: seconds.**

Using this I can track the user activities. I do some research but didn't found anything useful.

Is there any way to track the time a user spends on a page?

Comment: capture a timestamp in the OnAppearing and OnDisappearing events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.1)

```
Stopwatch timer;

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
  timer = new Stopwatch();
  timer.Start();
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
  timer.Stop();
  TimeSpan ts = timer.Elapsed;

  string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
}
```